# Dynamically show or hide a Div using *ngIf in Angular 9 based on dynamically generated dropdown value

Tags: css, angular

As said,  I am trying to dynamically show or hide a Div using *ngIf in Angular 9 based on the value selected from dynamically generated drop down with static options.

I am very new to Angular and I directly jumped to Angular 9. I have been working on a model webapp just to see if I can get the hang of the tech.

I have a page that renders div rows based on the number of JSON objects.

Each row is an accordion in itself and each expanded accordion will in turn have 2-3 rows. In the expanded accordion I have dynamically generated a dropdown on a column.

Based on the drop down selection I need to show/hide a div in the other column on same expanded accordion.

Please do not give me a long route by using a event and a method defined in Typescript, I mean please pour in solutions but I am looking to come through this problem in the HTML page itself.

As of now the webapp has only one JSON object in the name "incidents", this is how iterate them

```html
<div class="card" *ngIf='incidents && incidents.length' >
<div *ngFor = 'let incident of incidents ; let rowIndex = index'>
```

In the expanded Accordion am trying to achieve this.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="'fixType' + rowIndex">Type of Fix </label>
      <select id="'fixType' + rowIndex" class="form-control">
        <option selected>{{incident.TypeOfFix}}</option>
        <option value="1">Data Fix</option>
        <option value="2">Code Fix</option>
        <option value="3">User Education</option>
        <option value="4">Work Around</option>
        <option value="5">User Creation</option>
        <option value="6">Configuration Changes</option>
        <option value="7">Document Issue</option>
        <option value="8">SP/Script Changes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="'EstClsDt' + rowIndex">Estimated Closure Date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input #dp [id]="'EstClsDt' + rowIndex" class="form-control" placeholder="Estimated Closure Date"
          [value]="incident.EstimatedClosureDT" [(ngModel)]="model" container="body" ngbDatepicker
          #d1="ngbDatepicker">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d1.toggle()" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngIf="incident.TypeOfFix == 'Code Fix' || 'fixType' + rowIndex === '2'  ">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="'DepDt' + rowIndex">Deployment Date</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input #dp1 [id]="'DepDt' + rowIndex" class="form-control" placeholder="Estimated Closure Date"
          [value]="incident.EstimatedClosureDT" [(ngModel)]="model" container="body" ngbDatepicker
          #d2="ngbDatepicker">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d2.toggle()" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class = "col-md-4" *ngIf = "incident.TypeOfFix == 'Code Fix'">
```

This line is working and div is hidden/shown based on the value returned from the JSON object but when trying to show/hide the div in the runtime with the help of below line. 
I would need the correct version for the below line. There is no particular error thrown but the webapp does not react when I change the value of the drop down and div is neither shown nor hidden during runtime. I searched Online and people os different forums are suggesting to use ngModel or ngModule but if someone can help me with a clear syntax it would be great.

```html
<div class="form-group" *ngIf = "'fixType' + rowIndex == '2' " >
```

Hope I have detailed enough, Please HELP.
Thanks.

Comment: can you add the error?

Comment: try just removing incidents.length from the *ngIf. In the case that incidents is null, there is no attribute 'length' on it and will throw an error.

Comment: beware `'fixType' + rowIndex == '2'` is always `false`

Comment: Thanks all for replying. I have re-edited the question based on the comments.